# open current selection's tab in tabbed infoWindow container: ArcGIS Javascript API

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup, dojo

I am updating a webApp using ArcGIS Javscript API 2.1
I have an infoWindow with tabs which shows all of the features in my map. I built it based on this example:
http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm#jssamples/identify_drilldown.html

I would like to have the infoWindow open with the tab that matches the selected feature on top (or, selected). Currently, in my map and in the above example, the tab that opens is the tab last clicked during the preceding instance of the infoWindow.

I see there is a 'selected' property for tab containers. I can set it for the initial layout of the infoWindow onload in HTML, but setting it in the Javascript code does not seem to work..

Does anyone have an idea how I may do this? Thanks,

Comment: off-topic, but that site you referenced looks like it's scraping the [Esri sample site](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm), which is probably the more authoritative place to obtain samples

Comment: yes Stephen you're right, it is derived from here: [link] http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm#jssamples/identify_drilldown.html [/link]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.selectChild()](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/layout/TabContainer.html#manipulating-children).

In your example, if I click the map to identify, then run this in the console:

```
dijit.byId("tabs").selectChild("parcelTab")
```

The tab container in the info window switches to the "Tax Parcels tab. Running:

```
dijit.byId("tabs").selectChild("bldgTab")
```

Switches back to the "Buildings" tab.

Comment: Hello, I deleted my old comment. Thank you, now that I placed this function correctly, it works perfectly.

Comment: Glad it worked :).